# NodeJS Puppeteer Error in Windows Docker but not Windows10

Tags: node.js, docker, window, puppeteer

I could print PDF successfully when I am running on Windows10 `node puppeteer.js` directly. However, when I pushed to Windows Docker, I faced below error:

```
[2019-10-23T05:10:53.160Z] Puppeteer Error:
Error: Page crashed!
    at Page._onTargetCrashed (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:215:24)
    at CDPSession.<anonymous> (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:123:56)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:200:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:112:17)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\App\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\App\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:210:5)
[2019-10-23T05:10:53.370Z] Error for printPdf()
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
    at C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:183:56
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:182:12)
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:107:44)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:57:17)
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at WaitTask.rerun (C:\App\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:570:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  message: 'Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.'
}
```

Supplement Versions:

> **Chrome/Chromium:**
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
>
> **Windows:**
>   1903 or  10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
>
> **NodeJS packages:**
>   adal-node@0.2.1
>   azure-keyvault@3.0.5
>   azure-sb@0.11.1
>   azure-storage@2.10.3
>   http@0.0.0
>   puppeteer@1.20.0
>   puppeteer-core@1.20.0

Traced the error is from :

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => !!(window.Ext), {
    polling: LOAD_POLLING,
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT
});

log('Building document ...'); // this line okay to print out

await page.waitForFunction(() => !!(Ext.isReady), {
    polling: LOAD_POLLING,
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT
});
```

Comment: check if everything is same (versions of windows , chrome, puppeteer)

Comment: Hi @LinPy, added versions for reference and checked that they are in same versions.